# Android Netty 4 Client

Tags: java, android, netty, tcpclient

I try to create a simple tcp/ip client on Android with `Netty 4`. Now it working fine, but I have a problem with reconnect if device lost connection and get it again. 
My client code:

```
public class Client {

    private EventLoopGroup group;
    public static Bootstrap b;

    public void run() throws Exception {
        group = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        b = new Bootstrap();
        b.group(group)
                .channel(NioSocketChannel.class)
                .handler(new ClientInitializer(b));
        b.option(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true);
    }

    public void startConnection(){
        try {
            b.connect(Constants.HOSTNAME, Constants.PORT).sync().channel();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void closeConnection () throws Exception{
        group.shutdownGracefully();
    }
}
```

In activity through receiver I detect internet connection and if internet available I do next action:

`Client.b.connect(Constants.HOSTNAME, Constants.PORT);`

But new connection can't see server. What I am do wrong? May be all my way to do it wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure Netty 4 ever works on Android, although 3.x is known to work.  Making Netty 4+ running on Android is not our primary goal at the moment.  Pull requests are appreciated though.